# Adding billing and shipping progress in iwd checkout

Tags: checkout, billing, onepage-checkout

I am using IWD checkout suite free version and want to add billing and shipping address in right column just like it shows in Magento default one page checkout.
checkout image for reference.

[Demo image link](http://prntscr.com/dfhaa0)

There are two JS files in IWD checkout suite.I am able to print the billing and shipping but problem with sync with ajax of the plugin. If anyone has tried to do same thing, see this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your  demo link you need to use Magento default checkout

[Add to cart button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947514/add-to-cart-button-not-working)